# Why the data type of the value of a (Map object) changed?

Tags: java, jsf, data-structures, casting, hashmap

I have in my controller a `Map<String, Boolean>`

```
private Map<String, Boolean> selectedRequestsMap;
selectedRequestsMap = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
```

When i put elements in it added normally (as a `Boolean` value)

```
selectedRequestsMap.put(StringValue, booleanValue);
```

[image]
But when i loop over a Map to read the values
Its considered (as a `String` value)

```
// Loop over selectedRequestsMap
for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> entry : selectedRequestsMap.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Boolean value = entry.getValue(); // An Exception is raised 
    // ...  
}
```

[image]
Then When i read the `Boolean` value

`An Exception` is raised
`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean`

Need to know
How i can read a `Boolean` value normally ?

Comment: Either a ghost or the code changed the Boolean value to String. Usually it's the code. Something replaces the Boolean with its toString().

Comment: Give us some sample test data and exact stacktrace . In its current form , this should work.

Comment: You can't say that.... A malicious poltergeist can do that!

Comment: How are you using the collection (what do you do with it between putting in the values and the for each loop)?

Comment: Post the entire class and the usages...

Comment: It looks like some of your code might be changing the parametrized types of your Map. Then some other code actually puts a key value pair of String, String in the Map (hence, "someString", "true"). Try posting all the code that impacts on that specific Map.

Comment: Can you put some code how you are putting values into map..

Comment: No problem at all: http://browxy.com/SavedCode/4024

Comment: Don't get me wrong, we all get to situations where we think that the inexplicable is happening, but we just need to take a closer look at the code.

Comment: The code you show is fine.  Either your machine is hosed, or something that you haven't shown us is corrupting things.

Comment: How do you populate the map? You mentioned JSF: if you use it, show the corresponding code that you use to initialize the map and set its contents, otherwise, show the relevant code that deals with map data population. My guest is that you populate it with EL (that's reflection-based) with something that has a textual 'true' value.

Comment: The most plausible problem with your code is that the values derived from the request are in fact strings and not objects of other types. You might need to 'explain' JSF what type of values you expect to recieve by providing a converter. In this light not string `"true"` will be applied to the map entry, but rather `Boolean.TRUE`. This is because **reflection-based** and **runtime** EL language does not respect generics 'too much'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way how you manipulated the map value is broken. You have set a string value of `"true"` instead of the boolean literal `true`. That it passed the parameterized generic type constraint can only mean that it's been done via reflection. Considered that the question is asked in JSF context, this in turn means that you're manipulating the map's value in the view side with JSF tags and EL. In that case, you should not be specifying `"true"` in EL, but instead `#{true}`.

You didn't show the problem in SSCCE flavor, so it's hard to point out the mistake and provide an exact answer. So, here's just one of the most probable causes:

```html
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.selectedRequestsMap[some.key]}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="true" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="false" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

This is not only designtechnically wrong (you should have used a `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` instead), but this is also functionally wrong as it specifies the item values as plain strings instead of as real booleans. In this construct, EL won't be able to auto-coerce those strings to booleans because the parameterized generic type information of the map value is not available during runtime. EL has no idea that the map value is a boolean and without an explicit `converter`, it will thus put the plain unconverted string submitted value in there.

The fix would then be to explicitly specify them as booleans in EL context:

```html
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.selectedRequestsMap[some.key]}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="#{true}" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="#{false}" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

#### See also:

- [selectOneRadio component and Long value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788294/selectoneradio-component-and-long-value/9789392#9789392)
- [How to bind List<Integer> values to selectManyListbox in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865804/how-to-bind-listinteger-values-to-selectmanylistbox-in-jsf/13866179#13866179)
- [Unexpected behaviour of diamond interface in JDK7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986404/unexpected-behaviour-of-diamond-interface-in-jdk7/7986471#7986471)
- [How do I get selectManyCheckBox to return something other than List<String>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294284/how-do-i-get-selectmanycheckbox-to-return-something-other-than-liststring/7294491#7294491)
- [<h:selectManyListbox JSF and Enums Class Cast error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340762/hselectmanylistbox-jsf-and-enums-class-cast-error/5340825#5340825)